# A small part of the UI is not getting re rendered on state change

Tags: flutter, state

I have a text widget in the cellBuilder of [SF Datepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) in my app whose color should conditionally render on the basis of a state of a variable. When I change the state, the widget is getting re-rendered(the latest value of the state of the variable is printed and another text widget outside of cellBuilder which conditionally renders on the basis of the state also works fine). But the color of the text doesn't change.
This is the build method of the main widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        unfinishedWeeks.length > 0
            ? Text("Unfinished weeks")
            : Container(), //This text is visible when the state of unfinishedWeeks changes
        Container(
          height: 320,
          child: SfDateRangePicker(
            controller: _controller,
            cellBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, DateRangePickerCellDetails details) {
              debugPrint(unfinishedWeeks
                  .toString()); //the current state of unfinishedWeeks is printed
              return Text(
                details.date.day.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: unfinishedWeeks.length >
                          0 //this value doesn't change when the state of unfinishedWeeks changes
                      ? Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 0, 0)
                      : Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 15, 83),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Where am I going wrong? Does it have to do with SF Datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way: using [Keys to force the UI to re-render](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/how-to-force-a-widget-to-redraw-in-flutter#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20is%20to%20pass,rebuild%20of%20the%20stateful%20widget.). So I created a new widget enclosing the text widget and provided this widget with a key.

Answer (score 0):

SfDateRangePicker rebuild UI only when the onSelectionChanged function is called

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Comment: I try set key for SfDateRangePicker, it will update after setState()

```sh
 SfDateRangePicker(key: UniqueKey(), controller: _controller,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling `setState` on the section where `unfinishedWeeks` is being updated.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found another tricky way without setting keys. When the `maxDate` or `minDate` attribute from the `SfDateRangePicker` object changes during your `setState`, in other words, **the current view of the widget changes during your `setState`**, it will call the `onViewChanges` callback automatically.

This means that you can set a `minDate` or `maxDate` in a way that changes every time a new `setState` is called by setting its value, for example, the `minDate` as `DateTime.now()` or `maxDate` as one year into the front as follows: `maxDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:365)),`

After that change, every time you call `setState`, the `maxDate` will be different from the last time you had called, maybe by milliseconds, or seconds, or whatever, but it will be different. So, the `onViewChange` callback is called, and all `cellBuild` will be triggered again.

Here is your implementation with this fix:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        unfinishedWeeks.length > 0
            ? Text("Unfinished weeks")
            : Container(), //This text is visible when the state of unfinishedWeeks changes
        Container(
          height: 320,
          child: SfDateRangePicker(
            controller: _controller,
            // Start of the fix
            maxDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days:365)),
            // End of the fix
            cellBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, DateRangePickerCellDetails details) {
              debugPrint(unfinishedWeeks
                  .toString()); //the current state of unfinishedWeeks is printed
              return Text(
                details.date.day.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: unfinishedWeeks.length >
                          0 //this value doesn't change when the state of unfinishedWeeks changes
                      ? Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 0, 0)
                      : Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 15, 83),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

This worked on me.